# Do test data for machine learning need to have column names?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, test-data

Suppose I have a training data as below:

```
Age:12   Height:150   Weight:100     Gender:M
Age:15   Height:145   Weight:80      Gender:F
Age:17   Height:147   Weight:110     Gender:F
Age:11   Height:144   Weight:130     Gender:M
```

After I train my data and get the model, if I need to pass one test observation for prediction, do I need to send data with column names as below?

```
Age: 13   Height:142  Weight :90
```

I some cases I have seen people sending test data in an array without the column names. I am not sure how algorithms work.

Note: I am using python scikit-learn and my training data is a dataFrame. So I am not sure whether my test data should also be in dataFrame format

Answer (score 0):

Are you predicting gender?

If so, then yes. Your input are records with the columns: `Age`, `Height` and `Weight`.

Otherwise, you will be predicting on a record with a missing `Gender` value. You could get a `KeyError` if your model does not allow missing fields/columns.

> I am not sure whether my test data should also be in dataFrame format

In short: yes.

Usually you do this:

```
# X is your input data, the format depends on how your model (pre)process the data.
# It could be a numeric matrix, a list of dict's, a list of strings, etc.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
# Fit and validate.
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

So your train and test data are in the same format, or at least in compatible format (i.e.: a pandas dataframe is compatible with a `list` of `dict`'s).

Comment: Thanks Rolando.. Consider that I have trained the model with enough data using train_test_split or K-fold CV and done with the evaluation. Now I need to send only one test observation for prediction (say I am passing data from a front end tool), I need to find a way to put the input data from the user into corresponding column names  as a dataFrame  and pass it to the predict function right??

Comment: @GopalK Without seeing your code is hard to tell whether you strictly need to pass a dataframe or not. But yes, the input for `predict` is an array of observations in the same format you passed to `fit`.